# Authenticate a Parse.com user using ngCordovaOauth

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform, oauth, ionic-framework

I've started building a mobile app using Ionic, which in turn uses Cordova underneath. I want to use Parse.com's BaaS, and therefore I'm bound to using their Javascript SDK.

I want my users to signup using their Facebook, Twitter or Google accounts. Parse.com supports only a specific user signup/login using Facebook, but also has a [more generic User class](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.User.html) to work with.

The thing is, the generic User class requires a password for authentication/signup, and that's exactly what I want to avoid. I'm looking towards using [ngCordovaOauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth), which allows my users to authenticate using many different Oauth providers, but I don't have a clue how to let that play nicely with Parse.com. Would it be a good or bad to use the Oauth token as the password?

Any thoughts, pointers or code examples?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a slightly [differently phrased question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653507/how-to-signup-login-parse-user-from-authenticated-twitter-oauth-token-in-net?rq=1) here on StackOverflow in the .NET section, which pointed me to a tutorial that explains how to do it: https://parse.com/tutorials/adding-third-party-authentication-to-your-web-app